# Javascript Blob changes file

Tags: javascript, jquery, blob

I really have no prior knowledge to Blob objects in JavaScript aside from what I've read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) but need to use them to convert a string of binary data into a .xls file which I then make available to the user.  The catch is when I construct a blob, get the location, and open up the file to look at it, it opens up saying

> The file you are trying to open  is in a different format that
>   specified  by the file extension.  Verify that the file is not
>   corrupted and is from a  trusted source before opening the file.

(I know this data is incorrect because when I submit the form normally I get the file correctly and don't have this issue)

This is done in an ajax call and the success functions parameter data is the binary data.

```
$("#fileForm").submit(function(){
    var fileData = $("#fileInputElmt").prop("files")[0];
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("upload",fileData);
    var url = "process.action?" + $("#fileForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:url,
        data:data,
        cache:false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data){

            var bb = new Blob([data],
                 { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',endings:'native'});
            var bUrl = URL.createObjectURL(bb);
            window.open(bUrl,"_self");

            hideProgressBar();
        },error:function(data){
            hideProgressBar();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?  or is there a better way of doing this?